# На странице скрытых сообществ нет перевода для поля ввода

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице скрытых сообществ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/hidecommunities/wtf), когда сайтов больше 12, появляется поле ввода для поиска:

> [image: Поиск сообществ]

Можно заметить, что заголовок поля не переведён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил перевод вида:

> Показаны $num$ сообщества из $communityCount$ отображаемых

С учётом различных множественных форм. Будет на сайте после обновления Transifex и пересборки.